# Nav component refreshes on each page

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 app I have some pages that exists out of multiple components.

In my app.component.html I have this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in the html of the components something like this:

```
<div class="container dashboard page">
  <app-nav></app-nav>
  <div class="main">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Now when I load a page the nav and footer always refresh. It seems logical but is it right to assume that I need to do this in my app.component.html?

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Is this best practice and is there another way to avoid the nav and footer from refreshing?

Comment: If you have it outside of the routed component, it shouldn't refresh.

Comment: So I put the nav and footer in the app.component?

Comment: If your architecture allows that, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this best practice and is there another way to avoid the nav and
>   footer from refreshing?

Yes, it is. You don't want your "global components" to change with route changes, so don't place them inside "a component changing when route changes". Angular 2 is all about relations between components and their nesting is a crucial part when building an app :) .

Just a few arguments:

- If you put your global components within `router-outlet` you will repeat same code, which is against **DRY** rule. Imagine any changes to global components - you will have to update every single page component.
- It is a bad architecture if a state of global component totally depends on a router provided by Angular. Router is responsible for routing, and page components should be responsible for changes in global component, if it's state is in accordance with current page.
- Communication between global components and page components should be done with services with a RxJs subject. I've described it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4qhumr/communication_between_navbar_and_pages/d4t7mt8). This way, you can control the state of global component with a single object, which is a bridge between a page component and a global component.